# Configuring one to 0 or 1 relation in a relation table using fluent nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here are my classes:

```
public class User {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual IList<Bike> { get; set;}
}

public class Bike {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual string color { get; set;}
}

public class Accident{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual User User{ get; set;}
    public virtual Bike Bike{ get; set;}
}
```

And my tables

- User: Id
- Bike: Id, color, user(fk)
- Accident: Id
- AccdentOccurance: AccidentId, UserId, BikeId

An accident can be related to a bike(implicit to the user of the bike), or to a user, but not a bike.
My question is how do I configure the Accident ClassMap to work with the AccidentOccurance table?

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Lets see if I can get this right so it is helpful to you.

1. On the 3rd line, you left out "Bike" for the name you are assigning the 
   relation to.
2. Lines 4, 10 & 11, you were missing the reverse mappings.
   I added them with the following assumptions:
     a. A user can ride more than 1 bike.
     b. A user can be in more than 1 accident.
     c. A bike can be involved in more than 1 accident.
     d. A bike can only be used by 1 user.
        If you need the bike to be able to be used by more than 1 user
        change line 10 to: public virtual IList<User> User { get; set;}
        This will give you a Many to Many relationship.
3. I would merge the tables Accident and AccidentOccurance into 1 table 
   "Accident". Since if you kept them separated, you are looking at a 1 to 1 
   relationship that does not offer any special benefits. With the vast 
   majority of all 1 to 1 relationships, it is best to merge the tables to 
   limit the SQL queries and speed up your queries on large tables.


public class User {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual IList<Bike> Bike { get; set;} // Modified
    public virtual IList<Accident> Accident { get; set;} // Added
}

public class Bike {
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual string color { get; set;}
    public virtual User User { get; set;} // Added
    public virtual IList<Accident> Accident { get; set; } // Added
}

public class Accident{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set;}
    public virtual User User{ get; set;}
    public virtual Bike Bike{ get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael.
Thanks for the elaborate answer.
What it made me realize is that I have a unefficient table design, and to try to map it using nhibernate is a pain since nhibernate requires a logical table design. I think I'll change the tables as you have suggested.Thanks